# External disk volume not showing up in finder in Ventura

Tags: finder, macos-ventura

I have an external drive that does not show up in Finder under Ventura.

This drive appeared fine yesterday under Monterey 12.6.1, and for years before.  I use it with Carbon Copy Cloner to do full disk backups (not encrypted, not bootable). This drive has never been used on a different computer.

The drive hows up under `/Volumes/{volume name}` and I can access the files using the terminal or via Finder.

- Finder is set to show all items on Desktop
- Finder is set to show "Locations |> External Disks" in side bar
- Disk utility shows it
- Disk utility can navigate to it via "Show in finder"
- Volume `/Volumes/mybackupdrive` is present
- "Show hidden files" has no effect

I have tried the repair suggestions:

- In disk utility: `Run First Aid...`
- From command line `diskutil verifyVolume {volume}`

I have not run `diskutil repairVolume /Volumes/{volume}`, though.  I am not sure if that would modify it and break something.

`diskutil list` shows the volume, no difference from my internal

```
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         1000.0 GB  disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1000.0 GB  disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume mybackupdrive           737.8 GB   disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 20.5 KB    disk3s3
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                626.2 MB   disk3s4
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk3s5
```

Comment: Does it show if you start from 'my Mac name' in the sidebar > Locations?

Comment: @Tetsujin Under "Locations:" is "{my mac name}".  Clicking there shows "HDD" and "Network" only.

Comment: Assuming it shows as mounted in Disk Utility, I'm afraid I don't know. Maybe chalk it up to yet another Ventura bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing the same problem.
Note that it is restricted to APFS volumes. Disks formatted as Mac Extended are visible on desktop and in sidebar.
Interestingly, an external disk formatted as APFS which is a Time Machine repository is visible in both areas.

I have reported this to Apple.

UPDATE:
I have found that this affects APFS volumes created in earlier version of Mac OS (not sure how far back). Erasing and reloading the disk makes it visible. so, possibly related to a change in APFS code introduced in Ventura.
I have erased and re-created several volumes and in every case they are now visible both on Desktop and in finder sidebar.

Comment: I formatted my USB stick as APFS and it shows up properly, which supports your hypothesis.  I think that's the answer.